# Fire, catch and fire a particle

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics

To be more specific, would it be possible to perform the stern Gerlach experiment on a single electron multiple times provided that none of the electrons paths were blocked.

Comment: What do you understand by 'firing' and 'catching'?

Comment: You really need to add more information.  By "firing" you mean launched into projectile motion?   What do you mean by "particle"?  Add some context.  Your question might get closed because it's unclear what you are asking.  As it stands, it's hard to see a physics question.

Comment: I mean similar to what an electron gun would do but with one specific particle, and by catch I just mean someway to be able to fire it repeatedly.

Comment: Reuse the "same electron"?  I don't think so.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could set up a series of multiple SG experiments so that the electrons leaving one experiment entered the next.

If you're absolutely determined to use just the one piece of SG kit you'd need some form of magnetic guide to route electrons round in a circle back to the starting point. A bit like putting the SG experiment in the beam line of a (very low energy) synchrotron.

While possible in principle the cost would be sufficiently high that you'd need a very, very good reason to get the funding. It isn't obvious what physical insights would come from such an experiment.

Comment: Also, do you know if the particles spin could change between being measured